# What is the Root directoy in a Linux System?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am learning Shell Navigation on an Ubuntu system. I learnt that linux systems have only one topmost directory and all other directories are connected in the file tree.

I have always thought that `:/` is the root directory. However, I noticed that the contents of `:/`  and `:~` directories are different.

Which of the two is the `root` directory? and how are these two related on the file tree?

Comment: I unerstand it now. I understand that `/` is the root directory. When i ran `$HOME`, it returned `/root`. That implies that `~` is a subdirectory of the root directory.

Comment: That's right (though separately, don't be `root` when just exploring).